# What do you call exactly one kilogram of crows?

Tags: word, wordplay, humor

I came up with this terrible pun reading the latest Wen Spencer series and reading the history of French post revolutionary measurement.

> What do you call a kilogram of crows?

Hint:

> The answer is two words with a total of ten characters.

Comment: Relevant: a group of crows is called a murder.

Comment: To the close-voter: if this is too broad, please come up with an alternative solution which fits the question just as well as the one provided by Peregrine Rook.

Comment: This isn't that much of a puzzle, is it? It's just a joke.

Comment: Yeah, but a lot of the puzzles on this site are jokes, aren't they?

Comment: @Deusovi Well, you have to find resources to solve this puzzle, it puzzled me. (If it puzzled you, vote this comment.)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The answer is

> MASS MURDER

because a kilogram

> is a unit of mass,

and, as [greenturtle3141 pointed out](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/41970/what-do-you-call-exactly-one-kilogram-of-crows#comment124613_41970),

> a group of crows is called a "murder"
> (just as a group of lions is called a "pride", etc.)

Comment: ["Terms of venery"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Collective_noun#Terms_of_venery_.28words_for_groups_of_animals.29) is more specific than "collective noun" in this case.